# Raw query executor in Web Application - Production Environment

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, security, web-applications

I have an ASP.NET Web Application that is connected to a Database that is installed in several clients in production environment.

Some of those clients manage critical information (in other schemas, not accesible for the Web App, like people's money) so the access to execute scripts directly in the database to fix things in my Web App, if it's needed, requires **time** and also **approbation**, sometimes it takes weeks..

As some of my clients have a volatile reallity, my Web App has to manage a lot of changes in some short periods of time, that means script executions in the database to alter data or schema, and that means time waste !

Long story short, my question is, is it a good practice to implement a page, only for administrator users, that executes a raw query directly to database?
**Think in the scenario where security issue is managed properly.**
Something like: [Sql Pad](https://rickbergfalk.github.io/sqlpad/) where you cannot see the entire database system, just the query and the result as the target database is only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's a terrible idea. The security issue is probably not manageable - a web page that's available on the public internet which grants schema modification rights to the logged in user is a horrible security risk. Even if you can't get to another schema, you can easily bring the server to its knees by writing simple SQL which consumers all CPU, memory or disk space.

It's also terrible because you lose any track of what changes were installed in which environment.

If the IT department won't approve your scripts when run from management studio they certainly won't let you loose on your own via a web interface.

I've always solved this problem via automated deployment scripts - execute the schema changes etc. as a part of installing the new version of the web application. That way, you can do things like back up the database before running your changes, keep track of versioning and control access.